# Error in if statement at the colon

Tags: python

I am helping my friend with his new idea about prime numbers. I am writing a simple python code. I've encounter a SyntaxError that I don't know why. Thanks for any help

```
File "./prime.py", line 9 if isPrime(n) and isPrime(m) and isPrime(p):^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
##from __future__ import print_function
from math import floor, ceil, sqrt

def main():
    n = int(raw_input('Nhap so thu nhat: ')) #input number
    m = int(raw_input('Nhap so thu hai: ')) #input number
    p = int(raw_input('Nhap so thu ba: ') #input number
    if isPrime(n) and isPrime(m) and isPrime(p):
        step = 2
        q = n
        while q != n*n:
            if isPrime(q):
                print(q)
            q += step
            step += 2

def isPrime(n):
    if n <= 3:
        if n > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if n%2 == 0 or n%3 == 0:
        return False
    sqroot = int(n**.5)
    for i in range(5, sqroot + 1, 6):
        if n%i == 0 or n%(i+2) == 0:
            return False
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 p = int(raw_input('Nhap so thu ba: ')) <- add paren
```

A lot of times the syntax error is actually in the preceding line to what you see in the traceback.

Answer (score 4):

You have a missing `)` in the line

```
p = int(raw_input('Nhap so thu ba: ')
```

It should be

```
p = int(raw_input('Nhap so thu ba: '))
                                     ^
```